# Display different content based on domain

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, html

I currently run two domains on the same server.  Both websites use the same files.

Is it possible to utilize javascript or jquery or something else to display certain page content based on which domain the user is accessing from?

For example.  If user arrives from "www.site1.com" can I make the page display a different css template than if they access from "www.site2.com".

I hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Look at `document.domain`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.domain , or choose from the properties of `window.location`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Properties (like `host`)

Comment: Off topic: Google doesn't like identical content being used on different domains -- not good for SEO

Comment: Thanks I will ook into this :)

Answer (score 2):

In PHP: [Get current domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717249/get-current-domain)

In JavaScript: [Get The Current Domain Name With Javascript (Not the path, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401897/get-the-current-domain-name-with-javascript-not-the-path-etc)

Then you can do some if/else statements in either PHP or JavaScript and display your content accordingly.

Comment: Thanks I will ook into this also :)

Answer (score 0):

use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

and you can also check $_SERVER variable

var_dump($_SERVER);

[PHP manual:$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score -1):

You can check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` value to try to learn where **from** your user has came (it has nothing to do with the domain name of application he has came **to**). This value might be useful but you shouldn't depend on it, because it can be easily changed (it's one of the headers web browser **may** set when following a link).

Comment: That only tells you which page referred you to the current page (if it was supplied in the headers, of course).

Comment: and then he says 'access from' and as the rest reads i think its clear he wants to know what site they are on now.