# JS split OR Logical Operator

Tags: javascript, split, logical-operators

User inputs a web address that I want to get only the tail from, as I do know what site he inputs.

So first I want to remove the "main" URL and get what ever is at the end, so my action is:

*Original link: http://example.com/something*

```
var n=e.split("http://example.com/");e=n[1];
```

And I will get "something"

The problem is that site can also be secured, thus having https not http. Therefore the split wont work.

How do I define a split function, that would work like this:

```
split("http://example.com/ || https://example.com/")
```

I do not want to split by looking at "//" or anything of that sort, I want an exact address.

Comment: regular expressions are your friends ;)

Comment: How do you want  to split it?

Comment: I need to remove from the variable what I wrote: "http://example.com/ || https://example.com"

Comment: I can't understend you (( Could you say what you have on input  and what do you want to have on output?

Comment: `split(/https?:\/\/example\.com\//)` - is this what you have in mind? It's not 100% clear what your goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like it clear and want to avoid regular expressions, try this:

```
var n=e.split("http://example.com/",2).pop().split("https://example.com/",2).pop();
```

Comment: It does work, however, I can't get the whole string at the end with e=n[1]; as I could before.

Comment: You don't need `n[1]`, the result of the combination of `split()` and `pop()` is a string stored in `n`. If you want `e` to become this string, just add `e = n`.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to know the **host** you can do so by using this code instead in JavaScript:

```
window.location.host
```

Source [Get The Current Domain Name With Javascript (Not the path, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401897/get-the-current-domain-name-with-javascript-not-the-path-etc)

You can also use window.location.path to get the URL that was requested, combining those you get:

```
window.location.host + window.location.pathname
```

For me, this outputs stackoverflow.com/posts/25203020/edit while writing this reply.

Comment: It's not a current URL but the one the user inputs in a field.

Comment: You should be **very** careful accepting input from the user:
Wikipedia has this example URI:
 foo://username:password@example.com:8042/over/there/index.dtb?type=animal&name=narwhal#nose

While a valid 'url' that you can click on, it is very complex and not a case you can easily anticipate.

Comment: But I do know the start of a URL, it can either be that or that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "http://example.com/something";
function split (url) {
  var r = /([^:]+):\/\/([^\/]+)\/(.*)/gi;
  var a = r.exec(url)
  return [a[1], a[2], a[3]];
}
```