# How to extract only domain name from window.location object?

Tags: javascript

For example, I want extract only "google" from these mention hostnames

I don't want to retrieve host name, I just need the domain name without tld and subdomain(if it is there).

- https://www.google.com
- http://www.google.com
- http://analytics.google.com
- http://www.google.co.in
- http://www.google.co

etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get The Current Domain Name With Javascript (Not the path, etc.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401897/get-the-current-domain-name-with-javascript-not-the-path-etc)

Comment: `location.host`

Comment: Hey Thanks @dandavis for replying so promptly but I don't want to retrieve host, I just need domain name irrespective of any subdomain or tld.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well simply using `location.host` and extract the wanted part from it, this is a utility function that you can use:

```
function extractDomainName(hostname) {
    var host = hostname;
    host = host.replace(/^www\./i, "");
    host = host.replace(/(\.[a-z]{2,3})*\.[a-z]{2,3}$/i, "");
    return host;
}
```

It takes the whole `hostname` and returns only the domain name from it using `.replace()` method with `regex` to extract only the domain name.

You can see it workinh here.

**Demo:**

```js
function extractDomainName(hostname) {
  var host = hostname;
  host = host.replace(/^www\./i, "");
  host = host.replace(/(\.[a-z]{2,3})*\.[a-z]{2,3}$/i, "");
  return host;
}

var tests = ["www.google.com", "www.tutorialspoint.com", "somesite.gov.fr", "www.path.co.ltd"];

tests.forEach(function(hostname) {
  console.log(hostname);
  console.log(extractDomainName(hostname));
});
```

Comment: Thanks @chsdk but I need only domain name, not host.
for example: 
stackoverflow.com ==>  stackoverflow

Comment: I don't get it, can you please explain it.

Comment: I mean for the host www.stackoverflow.com solution should return only "stackoverflow" and similarly for the www.stackoverflow.co.in solution should return only "stackoverflow" only.

Comment: @shekhardtu You need to use `regex` and `string.replace()`to achieve it, please take a look at my Edit.

Comment: problem with these sort of filters as that you can't tell what dots to keep: `extractDomainName("secure.payments.google.co.uk")`

Comment: @dandavis it will give you `secure.payments.google`  as expected. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the hostname of the location object, you can check for the domain name before the TLD. This will ignore subdomains as well.

```js
var domain = window.location.hostname.match(/([a-z0-9-]*?)\.[a-z]{2,}$/)[1];

console.log(domain);
```