# Calling API in production and development in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

if the Url is localhost/8085

Then all api call will be made to localhost:9764/API

if the url is http://10.1xx.xx.xx:8085/Amp
Then all api call using 10.1xx.xx.xx:9764/api...

Is This possible in React js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works for me.

```
const url=""
if(process.env.NODE_EnV==="development"){
   url =localhost:8085
}else if(process.env.NODE_EnV==="production"){
   url = "http://10.1xx.xx.xx:8085/Amp "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the host name (window.location.host) and do anything from that (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54691801/7174186)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your app was created with [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/), you can create two different `.env` files - `.env.development` and `.env.production` and create inside them variables with the same names. Therefore, if you run your app locally, the app will use variable values from `.env.development` and in production from `.env.production`.

```
//.env.development
REACT_APP_API_URL=ABC
```

```
//.env.production
REACT_APP_API_URL=DEF
```

```
//Component.tsx
const URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
```